# Resize first image in div

Tags: jquery

I need to set specific width and height of image (in css), with jquery, but only for first image in one div. Is it posibble?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`#your_div` is refers to div that contains image, may be you've something else.

```
$('#your_div img:first').css({
   height: 200, // also use '200px' or something other
   width: 200  // '200px' or something other
});
```

alternative of `img:first` is `img:eq(0)`.

Read about jQuery [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first) and [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq)

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#myDiv img:first").width(100).height(100);
```

Here is [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LTsSc/) example.

Answer (score 2):

try with it:

```
$('#yourDiv img:first-child').css({width:'100px',height:'100px'});
```

Comment: The same as the answer from @thecodeparadox, which will default to pixels.